# What cause of unknown characters appearing to your visualforce page?

Tags: visualforce, character-encoding

I don't know If anyone has experienced this, while I was making some changes to my visualforce page, saved it and reloaded the page, I had exception that there were unknown characters in my visualforce page. I don't know what have caused that, and it's kind of weird it was like being generate to my page. Would that has something to do with encoding? I could not give a sample of the unknown characters, because I haven't thought asking about it to this site since all I have to do is removed them and there will be no errors.

Comment: How were you making changes to your VF pages ? In salesforce, dev console, IDE, ...  ?

Comment: Kindly share your VF page and also the source from which the error is raised. (like mentioned by @SamuelDeRycke )

Comment: @SamuelDeRycke via IDE, I was editing a visualforce page of salesforce. It's been a month or two since I have the error. I was just curious to ask about it, it happens again with my Project Manager. I was not able to get it from her, when she mention about it she fixed it already. I know there is a little chance since I do not have those unknown characters. I'm just editing some codes, if I still remember that happened when I was trying to initialize an object because before that happened there was an error about null reference. If this information help, I'm also using jquery tabs in the page.

Comment: I know now why this happens. Whenever we use a special character (e.g. symbol for summation) instead of `html` code and save the page, it generates unknown characters. We recently experience this again.

Comment: Yes, I have experienced that somehow Eclipse + Force.com IDE does not properly handle things with, e.g., é in it.